# Resolving the missing loader to handle the file type in a third-party module in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm working with a third-party module for a React application which includes implementing a chatbot. After installing the module and incorporating the component inside another one as below:

```
import SidePanel from "./SidePanel/SidePanel";
import Messages from "./Messages/Messages";
import MetaPanel from "./MetaPanel/MetaPanel";
import {Chatbot} from 'react-chatbot-kit';

function App({ currentUser, currentChannel, isPrivateChannel, userPosts, primaryColor, secondaryColor }) {
  return (
    <Grid columns="equal" className="app" style={{ background: secondaryColor }}>
      <SidePanel
        key={currentUser && currentUser.uid}
        currentUser={currentUser}
        primaryColor={primaryColor} />

      <Grid.Column style={{ marginLeft: 320 }}>
        <Messages
          key={currentChannel && currentChannel.id}
          currentChannel={currentChannel}
          currentUser={currentUser}
          isPrivateChannel={isPrivateChannel} />
      </Grid.Column>

      <Grid.Column width={4}>
        <MetaPanel
          key={currentChannel && currentChannel.name}
          userPosts={userPosts}
          currentChannel={currentChannel}
          isPrivateChannel={isPrivateChannel} />
      </Grid.Column>

      <Grid.Column>
        <Chatbot/>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Instead of giving the expected output (that of a dialoging window with a chatbot) it gives the following error followed by a bunch of code in the index.js file.

```
./node_modules/react-chatbot-kit/build/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:15703)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

It specifically points out to this line and its first comma:

```
return e}).apply(this,arguments)}var d=({styles:e={},...t})=>o.a.createElement("svg",p({xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",viewBox:"0 0 512 512"},t)
```

I've been banging my head against the wall for some time trying to resolve this. How can it be fixed?

EDIT: Adding devDependencies

package.json of my project

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.1",
  }
```

react-chatbot-kit/package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "7.9.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react-svg-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.11"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have svg loader.
First install svg loader with this command:

```
npm i svg-url-loader --save-dev
```

Next,add this code to webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  ...
};
```

Then,for example this code

```
const App = () => <img src={rectangle} alt="" />;
```

would be translated into this:

```
<img src="ebbc8779488b4073081931bd519478e8.svg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but where is the webpack config file located? Is it the 'webpack.config.dev' or 'webpack.config.prod'?

Comment: Did you use create-react-app for the project?Most of the time I manually configure react and webpack from the start,so I have one webpack.config.js file and there I add the stuff I need for the project and necessary loaders.